# Send a serial message before closing the serial port in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port

I'm trying to develop an user interface in Qt for an academic project, which sends serial messages to a microcontroller. I'm struggling with the closing of the serial port though: the user interface should send a serial message to the microcontroller before closing the serial port. This is the portion of the code which manages this operation:

```
device->write(QString("ABORT___").toStdString().c_str());
displayMessage("Disconnected");
deviceIsConnected = false;
device->close();
ui->PortComboBox->setEnabled(true);
ui->tabWidget->setEnabled(false);
ui->ConnectButton->setText("Connect");
ui->ConnectionStatus->setText("<span style=\" color:#e1d41f;\">DISCONNECTED</span>");
```

The problem is that this code closes the port before that the message is actually sent, in fact if i try to comment this line `device->close();` the code works as expected. It seems like that the port is closed before the message is sent, even if the line that manages the port closing is after.
Even if i try to nest the `device->close();` line in some if statements, the issue persists.

Can you help me?

Comment: Can you check in your debugger whether ``device->write`` returns ``-1`` in your case?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I checked if  `device->write` returns `-1` with the following code `qDebug() << device->write(QString("ABORT___").toStdString().c_str());` and it returned `8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should close the port once the [`bytesWritten`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#bytesWritten) signal has been emmitted

Alternatively you can call [`waitForBytesWritten`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#waitForBytesWritten)

> For buffered devices, this function waits until a payload of buffered written data has been written to the device and the bytesWritten() signal has been emitted, or until msecs milliseconds have passed. If msecs is -1, this function will not time out. For unbuffered devices, it returns immediately.